# What is the relation between UUID and a disk image?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, uuid

In order to create two VMs on VirtualBox for same Fedora 17 vdi, I first installed Fedora, then I copied Fedora17.vdi using dd command. Then I changed the UUID of the new image using the command

```
$ VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid /home/pradeep/Fedora_New.vdi "NewUUID"
```

But this doesnot work..I am interested to know what is the relation between the UUID value of a disk and its disk image and how it is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

How did you use dd to create the copy? My guess is that is where things went south most likely.

The best way to duplicate a virtual disk image is to use the [clonehd](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi) command:

```
VBoxManage clonehd original.vdi copy.vdi
```

This will also clean up the UUID as the copy is created.